# Newbie confusion on introduction to proofs.

Tags: proof-explanation

My problem: Show that if $3$ is a factor of $2n$ then $3$ is also a factor of $n$.

Solution: If $3$ is a factor of $2n$ **then some integer constant $k$ exist such that $3k=2n$.** Now, $2n$ is even hence $3k$ is even and $k$ is even and so $k$ is divisible by $2$

My question: I don't understand the 'some integer constant exist' part. What does this mean and where does it come from?

Comment: The existence of such $k$ is what it means for $3$ to be a factor of $2n$.

Comment: If $p$ is divisible by $q$ then, by definition, $\frac{p}{q}=k$ for some $k$ so $p=kq$.

Answer (score 1):

That is a definition:

a is a factor of b if there exists some integer constant k such that $b = ak$.